# Change Timezon on Update

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `table` in `MySQL` that has 3 `columns` with `datetime` field and 10,000 `rows`

my mySQL timezone is `UTC, +0000` How can I convert the table column in our timezone? I mean philipine timezone?

For example

`UPDATE TableName SET Column TimeZone From UTC, +0000 to Phil Time Zone` and I hope it will not damage the data.

tysm.

Comment: Are you sure you want to hardcode the timezone in your columns? Why don't you store data in a global timezone like UTC and adjust it to the local timezone on output?

Comment: Well actually that way looks fine for me. It lessens my worries.You mean I will stick to my original code that it will save as UTC then when I use `Select` I will convert it in UTC+8 (Phil Time)

Comment: Are you aware of the timestamp datatype? Read [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) at "MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values..."

Comment: @fancyPants by using this way, you need to specify the timezone for your database connection. By just using UTC in the database and converting the date in your application alone, you have only one single point to adjust the timezone if needed